# install uuid-dev on heroku

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, shared-libraries, uuid

- uuid-dev is unavailable by default
- sudo apt-get installation does not work

How can one install uuid-dev to an appropriate location on heroku, ideally using buildpacks.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37643412/1011803

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess

```
echo 'uuid-dev' > Aptfile
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-buildpack-apt
```

References:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app
- https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt
- https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt

Answer (score 0):

Add Buildpacks in app settings

```
Go to your app-> setting -> under `Buildpack' you can add mulitple buildpacks
```

> https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt

Even though this buildpack is no longer maintained but still it will work for you.

```
Note : You can directly visit  https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<app_name>/settings where you can find section with heading  "Buildpacks".
```