# How to install libffi-dev on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I need to have libffi-dev running on my Heroku servers to compile some packages I'm using. How does one install dependencies such as this on Heroku?

Answer (score 5):

I've never done so, but I think custom binary buildpacks might be helpful in such scenarios: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-binaries

Comment: This is definitely the right direction -- thank you, Yuval (you get an upvote from me!) I'd love to hear if anyone has actually gone through the process of making a buildpack, and especially with the libffi-dev package.

Answer (score 0):

### Add Buildpacks

Add in `https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<your_app_name>/settings` in section "**Buildpacks**" these links:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python
https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt
https://github.com/coderanger/heroku-buildpack-cffi
```

---

Like this for example:

[image]

---

### Helpful links

There are also helpful resources:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-binaries
- https://coderanger.net/heroku-cffi/